# React select dropdown not setting the right value

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a form on my website with a default value of ethExperienceLevel set to "BEGINNER". I have a function to change the selected state when I switch between options in a select element dropdown list with an onChange handler. However, e.target.value of the selected element is always the currently selected option's value, but when I am setting that to ethExperienceLevel on the form the value gets set to one option that was previously selected before the onChange. I do not understand why.

```js
const [form, setForm] = useState<IHackerInput>({
    email: '',
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    website: '',
    github: '',
    linkedIn: '',
    yearsOfSoftwareExperience: 0,
    ethExperienceLevel: 'BEGINNER',
    motivation: 'ATTENDWORKSHOPS',
    priorBuilds: '',
    lookingToBuild: '',
    rulesAccepted: false,
  })

  const handleETHExperienceSelect = (
    e: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>,
  ): void => {
    if (
      e.target.value === 'BEGINNER' ||
      e.target.value === 'INTERMEDIATE' ||
      e.target.value === 'EXPERT'
    ) {
      console.log(e.target.value) // correctly selected option value
      setForm({ ...form, ethExperienceLevel: e.target.value })
      console.log(form.ethExperienceLevel) // option before selected change 
    }
  }
```

```html
                <label
                  htmlFor="ethExperienceLevel"
                >
                  What's your experience level with Ethereum?
                </label>
                <select
                  id="ethExperienceLevel"
                  onChange={(e) => handleETHExperienceSelect(e)}
                >
                  <option value="BEGINNER">beginner</option>
                  <option value="INTERMEDIATE">intermediate</option>
                  <option value="EXPERT">expert</option>
                </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that `setForm` is executed asynchronously by React, so it is not guaranteed to be executed immediately after you call it, to be notified the exact moment when React execute `setForm` (and therefore the value of `form` changes) you will have to watch for the changes in `form`, so we need to use `useEffect`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // actions to perform when the form value changes
}, [ form ]) // here we are watching for changes in form
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I put form into a useEffect hook and noted the correctly changed options in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is related to how `setState` works in react.js.`setState` is an async operation but it does not return a Promise, so you cannot use `await` or `then`

`setState` will cause your component rerendering and when your component rerenders, you will have the updated state value. However, for the performance reason, react decides when to rerender the component.

when you called `console.log(form.ethExperienceLevel)` your component has not been rerendered. if you run  `console.log("chekcing the update",form.ethExperienceLevel)` outside the function, last console will be the updated the value.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I put form into a useEffect hook and noted the correctly changed options in the console.

Comment: be careful with `useEffect`. if your dependency is state and you update the state inside `useEffect` this will cause infinite loop